# Add gem based on server name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, bundler

So i'm using capistrano to deploy to two separate servers.

I'm wanting to add newrelic to only 1 of the servers and can't find a way to do it based on hostname.  Does anyone know of a way to do something like this

```
if (hostname==someserver)
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way would be to use two different environments for the servers, just like `development` and `production`. These are pre-configured by default, but you can add as many environments as you like and give them any name. On your machine you can then set the environment with

```
export RAILS_ENV=server1
```

and on the other machine

```
export RAILS_ENV=server2
```

How you need set the `RAILS_ENV` will depend on your particular server setup; for example, [Passenger has a dedicated option for this](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerAppEnv). Then, you can use these environments as groups in your Gemfile:

```
group :server1
  gem 'only_on_server1'
end

group :server2
  gem 'only_on_server2'
end
```